# Laravel socialite

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have used laravel auth and socialite package in my web app. I have followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uavoKwhGBKI&t=932s link and it working fine.To be brief, If I register using socialite it fetches the name of the user and email but needs to be filled other details as DOB and password but if I submit without filling that it shows 500 error while if I register without socialite then my validation works fine.The registration page is same.

Comment: I make debug_report true then it shows error Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request"

Answer (score 0):

Socialite only gives you access to a select set of data returned from a successful connection.

**# Retrieving User Details**
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite#retrieving-user-details

```php
$user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();

// OAuth Two Providers
$token = $user->token;
$refreshToken = $user->refreshToken; // not always provided
$expiresIn = $user->expiresIn;

// OAuth One Providers
$token = $user->token;
$tokenSecret = $user->tokenSecret;

// All Providers
$user->getId();
$user->getNickname();
$user->getName();
$user->getEmail();
$user->getAvatar();
```

**# Modifying LoginController**
https://scqq.blogspot.com/2017/11/laravel-55-socialite-login-with-twitter.html

This guide you followed does not actually register a user by social platform.  It only pre-populates the default Laravel registration form with the fields `name` and `email` as shown below.  This is where you can add another property from above, such as the user's avatar, if desired. You would also need to add the corresponding field to the registration form.

```php
return view('auth.register', [
    'name' => $userSocial->getName(),
    'email' => $userSocial->getEmail(),
    // ... 'avatar' => $userSocial->getAvatar(),
]);
```

**Google is NEVER going to give you someone's password!**
The whole point of Socialite is to allow Google (or the selected provider) to authenticate the user — not your application.

If you wish to actually register a user with Socialite (without any additional forms or setting a password), you will need to modify or extend **RegisterController.php** to be able to support this.